# How to handle deprecated 'ready' model lifecycle hook in ember-data?

Tags: ember-data, ember-octane

I am currently transferring from Ember 2.18 to Ember 3.16. In my models I make use of the ready function to create default values for relationships if a new instance is created.

```
// app/models/human.js
import Model, { hasMany } from '@ember-data/model';

export default Model.extend({
    personalities: hasMany('personality')
    ready () {
        // because you should have at least one
        if (this.isNew) {
            this.get('personalities').pushObject(this.store.createRecord('personality'));
        }
    }
});
```

The ready function had the beauty that the whole internal state is set correctly when accessing `this.isNew`.

Trying to shift to the ES6 class approach would yield into somehting like this:

```
// app/models/human.js
import Model, { hasMany } from '@ember-data/model';

export default class HumanModel extends Model {
    @hasMany('personality') personalities;
    constructor () {
        super(...arguments);
        // because you should have at least one
        if (this.isNew) {
            this.personalities.pushObject(this.store.createRecord('personality'));
        }
    }
}
```

But this fails because `this.isNew` can't access the internal state yet.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentState' of null
```

Is there a way to address that by keeping that confined to the model? I would want to avoid creating a factory or builder service. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use init() method instead of constructor (init method is not deprecated). As far as I understand, using constructor is recommended for components, not Models

```
init() {
  this._super(...arguments);
  //your code here
}
```